# Spinner personalizado no muestra letra completa

Tags: android-layout, spinner

buenas a todos!!

Tengo un problema con la apariencia gráfica de la aplicación.

He puesto dos spinner, y he puesto la letra de los mismos más grandes mediante un layout con un TextView donde pongo las características que quiero para la letra de mi spinner, en este caso tamaño de 20sp. Luego en el fichero java al usar el adapter del spinner le incorporo el tamaño de la letra.

Pues el problema es que en el spinner no aparece el texto compelto, sale cortado. No sé si al cambiar el tamaño de la letra habra que cambiar alguna propiedad del spinner para que sea más grande y así no corte la letra.

Muchas gracias, os dejo el código:

**Layout TextView spinner:**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/green"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**Layout activity:**

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="@string/seleccPlan"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planta"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp" />
```

**Código Java activity:**

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterP = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.planta,R.layout.textview_spinner);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapterP.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        this.spPlanta.setAdapter(adapterP);
```

Comment: Agrega una captura de como se ve el spinner.

Comment: @David, es un problema del atributo android:layout_height="25dp", para un tamaño de 20sp de letra es muy bajo, le he subido a 42 y se ve perfecto. Gracias por el interés

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es del atributo height del spinner. Puedes aumentarlo o cambiarlo a wrap_content.
Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Como ha comentado @D. Santamaría, el problema es el atributo height del spinner, el decía wrap_content, yo he puesto esto:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planta"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/deposito"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

ambas soluciones valen!! Muchas gracias